# Inserting String into byte array at certain index in Java

Tags: java, arrays, byte, record, sector

I would like to insert a string value into a specific range of indexes in an already declared byte array.  How would I do this?

```
byte [] sector = new byte[SECTORSIZE];
String str1 = "Sector 0, Record 0";
//I want to insert str1 into sector at indexes 0 - str1.length()
String str2 = "Sector 0, Record 1";
//I want to insert str2 into sector at indexes 128 - str2.length() + 128
```

Comment: [`String.getBytes(charset)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes-java.nio.charset.Charset-)

Comment: I knew that one from a little research.  Ok so now that you get the strings to be byte arrays, how do you insert those arrays into specific positions in the sector array?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After you get the arrays of bytes for your strings you can use

```
   System.arraycopy(src, srcPos, dest, destPos, length);
```

see java docs for this method for more info